# Android data binding - cannot find getter for <> that accepts parameter type 'long'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I have been using data binding for the past few weeks and now am trying to use a two way data binding for a custom view with a 'value' attribute.

My problem is that I get the following error when building.

> Cannot find a getter for <com.twisthenry8gmail.dragline.DraglineView
> app:value> that accepts parameter type 'long'

Now it was my understanding that the binding library will automatically use my public setters and getters however the most confusing part is adding a redundant inverse binding adapter seems to solve the problem? So I get the impression that it is using my setter without needing an adapter but this is not the case for the getter?

**My custom view**

```
class DraglineView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
    ...

    var value = 0L
        set(value) {

            draggedValue = value
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    ...
}
```

**My view in the layout file**

```
<com.twisthenry8gmail.dragline.DraglineView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:increment="@{viewmodel.type.minIncrement}"
    app:minValue="@{viewmodel.type.minIncrement}"
    app:value="@={viewmodel.target}" />
```

**My seemingly redundant adapter**

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "value")
@JvmStatic
fun getValueTest(draglineView: DraglineView): Long {

    return draglineView.value
}
```

**My attribute changed adapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("valueAttrChanged")
@JvmStatic
fun setDraglineListener(draglineView: DraglineView, listener: InverseBindingListener) {

    draglineView.valueChangedListener = {

        listener.onChange()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when using two-way data binding between my data object and a custom NumberPicker (error message at compile time: *Cannot find a getter for <com.shawnlin.numberpicker.NumberPicker **app:np_value**> that accepts parameter type 'int'* ).

The library I am using for the NumberPicker is https://github.com/ShawnLin013/NumberPicker and, according to its documentation, the current value should be set using *np_value*. It works correctly (the value gets initialized as required), except the two-way databinding which is giving me the error above.

However, changing **app:np_value** to **android:value** (in the annotations and in the layout) solved the issue.

In your case, you can try replacing

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "value")
@BindingAdapter("valueAttrChanged")
app:value="@={viewmodel.target}
```

with

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:value")
@BindingAdapter("android:valueAttrChanged")
android:value="@={viewmodel.target}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that databinding system doesn't know when the view changes the *value*.

[InverseBindingAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter) not only describes how to retrieve the *value* from the view, but it also defines an optional [event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter#event) property which will receive an [InverseBindingListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingListener) instance. The default event name is the attribute name suffixed with "AttrChanged".

Now let's look at your `setDraglineListener()` adapter. It processes `valueAttrChanged` attribute added by `InverseBindingAdapter` and receives `InverseBindingListener`. The only thing is left is to notify the listener when the *value* is changed by calling `listener.onChange()`;

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't think it quite answers my question. What I really want to know is why it is necessary to have an inverse binding adapter in the first place? Especially as it seems to have no problem using the setter without an adapter, so why does it need one for the getter? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HenryTwist I'm sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly. I updated my answer, hope it helps you now. If you still have any questions, fell free to ask.

Comment: Sorry if I am not being clear, all the code in my original question is working fine and produces the result I expect. What I am confused about is the way that the data binding library generates it's code. In order for two way binding to work, I would assume it must have access to a setter, a getter and some way to know when the value changes (the listener). However the binding works without providing a binding adapter for the setter, which means it must use the matching setter automatically. So why can it not do this with the getter as well. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: I recommend you not to use "value" attribute, because it's already used in material.Slider view and with future updates to androidx.databinding you will probably have your Sliders broken.

Comment: @HenryTwist Unfortunately I cannot say why it's designed this way. In your case the getter adapter logic is straightforward and indeed it looks like it could be generated automatically, in case you use the default event name. May be it's harder to implement, or there're some other reasons.

Comment: Thanks @StayCool I will change that!

Comment: Thanks for your help @ValeriyKatkov, I guess I am just confused why it has no issue generating a setter, but cannot do the same for the getter!

Comment: An adapter is bound to a specific view type but not just to an attribute name. So don't worry, it's ok to use same attribute names for different views.