# How to create Binding Adapter for material.Slider view?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, slider, android-binding-adapter

My goal is to 2-way databind material.Slider view to MutableLiveData from my viewmodel:

```
   <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
        ...
        android:value="@={viewmodel.fps}"
        ...
    />
```

Of course, it's not working because there is no databinding adapter for Slider in androidx.databinding library

```
[databinding] Cannot find a getter for <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider android:value> that accepts parameter type <java.lang.Integer>. If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

But, they have one for SeekBar: [/androidx/databinding/adapters/SeekBarBindingAdapter.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/SeekBarBindingAdapter.java)

As I understand, 2-way databinding should work only with "progress" attribute, and 1-way databinding requires two attributes: "onChanged" and "progress"

I made a try to adapt SeekBarBindingAdapter for Slider:

```
    @InverseBindingMethods({
            @InverseBindingMethod(type = Slider.class, attribute = "android:value"),
    })
    public class SliderBindingAdapter {
        @BindingAdapter("android:value")
        public static void setValue(Slider view, int value) {
            if (value != view.getValue()) {
                view.setValue(value);
            }
        }

@BindingAdapter(value = {"android:valueAttrChanged", "android:onValueChange"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void setOnSliderChangeListener(Slider view, final Slider.OnChangeListener valChanged, final InverseBindingListener attrChanged) {
        if (valChanged == null)
            view.addOnChangeListener(null);
        else
            view.addOnChangeListener((slider, value, fromUser) -> {
                if (valChanged != null)
                    valChanged.onValueChange(slider, value, fromUser);
            });


        if (attrChanged != null) {
            attrChanged.onChange();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {

    }
```

It's not building:

```
Could not find event android:valueAttrChanged on View type Slider
```

but why it looks for valueAttrChanged if I only use

```
android:value="@={viewmodel.fps}"
```

?

How do I find the right attribute to add to BindingAdapter, if I don't see valueAttrChanged in Slider class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look at [SeekBarBindingAdapter's](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/refs/heads/studio-master-dev/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/androidx/databinding/adapters/SeekBarBindingAdapter.java) `setOnSeekBarChangeListener()` method. It adds four different attributes: `{"android:onStartTrackingTouch", "android:onStopTrackingTouch", "android:onProgressChanged", "android:progressAttrChanged"}` but only the last one is used by two-way databinding.

But why there are four attributes? If you look at [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar) class, it has `setOnSeekBarChangeListener()` method which allows you to set and remove a listener. The problem is that SeekBar can only have one listener, and that [listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) provides different callbacks: `onProgressChanged`, `onStartTrackingTouch` and `onStopTrackingTouch`.

`SeekBarBindingAdapter` registers its own listener which means that no one can register another listener without removing the existing one. It's why `SeekBarBindingAdapter` provides `onStartTrackingTouch`, `onStopTrackingTouch` and `onProgressChanged` attributes, so you can listen to these events without registering your own `OnSeekBarChangeListener`.

Actually the `Slider` adapter can be much simpler than `SeekBarBindingAdapter`, because the Slider allows you to add and remove listeners using `addOnChangeListener()` and `removeOnChangeListener()`. So a two-way databinding adapter can register its own listener and anyone else can register other listeners without removing previous ones.

It allows us to define a pretty concise adapter. I created a kotlin example, hope you can translate it to java:

```kotlin
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:value")
fun getSliderValue(slider: Slider) = slider.value

@BindingAdapter("android:valueAttrChanged")
fun setSliderListeners(slider: Slider, attrChange: InverseBindingListener) {
    slider.addOnChangeListener { _, _, _ ->
        attrChange.onChange()
    }
}
```

And the layout:

```xml
...
<com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
    ...
    android:value="@={model.count}" />
...
```

You can find the full sources [here](https://github.com/icesmith/android-samples/tree/master/SliderDatabinding).

Comment: Seems legit, will try your solution and give a feedback.
But, why do you setSliderListeners?
Do setSliderValue and getSLiderValue is enough for 2-way-databinding?

Comment: @StayCool Ok, hope it helps you! According to the [two-way databinding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#two-way-custom-attrs) a *listeners* adapter should be setup to let the databinding system know that the value is changed. If you provide only a *getter* and a *setter* it would be able to get and set the value but won't be able to determine when the value is changed.

Comment: I see. Here is my mistake was. You said you had problems with "android:value" attr, and I think that's why my modified SeekBarAdapter failed to work, because I used "android:valueAttrChanged". What is wrong with that value? Why another basic attrs (text, checkedButton, etc) works perfectly?

Comment: @StayCool Properties line `text` work because they have [build-in two-way databinding attributes](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way). But there are no configured attributes for the material Slider. According to [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/926)  GitHub issue android material components don't proved preconfigured adapters. What is about `android:value`, I guess it conflicts somehow with some of the existing definitions, but don't know the exact reason.

Comment: I just had no knowledge about why my custom adapter with same attr name (value) could not work. Not it's clear for me that it's some kind of conflict, but still I can't realize why, because "built-in" adapters guys from androidx.databinding write doesn't really differ from which I or you did.

Comment: @StayCool Please look at the updated answer. Finally I figured out how to use the `value` attribute, it allows us to get rid of a custom *setter* adapter. I've also updated the sample repo. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your time and so detailed answer! 
But I still have two questions, which are actually above the topic question, so I don't suppose that you will answer :
1. How androix.databinding adapters are using "android" namespace for their attrs names, and why we can't? They are kind of override the value attribute from android namespace? [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/master/extensions/baseAdapters/src/main/java/android/databinding/adapters/SeekBarBindingAdapter.java) 2. Is new listener is setup everytime slider fires valueAttrChanged?

Comment: @StayCool Glad to help you. `setSliderListeners()` is called only once per a view while its initialization, you can check it by adding a log to the function. A binding adapter called every time the bound value is changed, but in case of two-way databinding `valueAttrChanged` is initialized only once. What about `android` namespace, its reserved for built-in android attributes, the app specific attributes should use 'app' namespace. I cannot say how this rule is bypassed by androidx libraries, but androidx it's part of android sdk, so I think they know some secrets :)

Comment: @StayCool Finally I ended up using 'android' namespace, it seems ok for an 'android' attribute. I just tried it again and it works fine. I don't know the exact reason why it didn't work when I tried it before. I updated the answer. You can also look at my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62130750/4858777) describing how `InverseBindingAdapter` and `BindingAdapter` work together, maybe it will be interesting to you too.

Comment: Hi @ValeriyKatkov This help so much, thanks a lot

Comment: @Valerity `private val _count = MutableLiveData<Float>()
    val count: LiveData<Float>
    get() = _count` I need to expose the slider value as LiveData in my XML but the app is crashing. Any leads around this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update Android Java**

Data binding

```
<variable
        name="device"
        type=".....Device" />
```

Trong file binding

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:value")
public Float getSlider(Slider slider) {
    return slider.getValue();
}

@BindingAdapter("app:valuesAttrChanged")
public void setSliderListeners(Slider slider, InverseBindingListener attrChange) {
    slider.addOnChangeListener(new Slider.OnChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(@NonNull Slider slider, float value, boolean fromUser) {
            attrChange.onChange();
        }
    });
}
```

Trong file xml thêm dòng

```
android:value="@{device.data}"
```

**data is value change**