# How to create Binding Adapter for material.Slider(range) view?

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-databinding

I found a [solution for material.Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62026687/how-to-create-binding-adapter-for-material-slider-view) with one thumb, but i need the same for range slider. I need get min and max values from slider.
How i can get values from range slider with bindingAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LiveData` for it. So, your `bindingAdapter` is going to look like this.

```
@BindingAdapter("onChange")
fun bindOnChange(rangeSlider: RangeSlider, onChangeLiveData: MutableLiveData<Float>) {
    rangeSlider.addOnChangeListener(RangeSlider.OnChangeListener { _, value, _ ->
        onChangeLiveData.postValue(value)
    })
}
```

You can use this as

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:onChange="@{passYourOnChangeMutableLiveDataHere}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: please, can you share the example of liveData for RangeSlider (it must have 2 values min/max)?

Comment: your suggestion works, but livedata only gets one value (last changed) when I need a range (from X to Y)

Comment: @user14729932 sorry I don't follow? Do you want the previous and the changed value?

Comment: i have corrected your answer to be the way it should work. Thanks, your suggestion helped to solve my problem.

Comment: @user14729932 i saw your edit. What would I suggest you is to use a `Pair` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

More general and more useful solution:

Create Function in your `ViewModel` (or anywhere else really) to be called `onChange`:

```
val onValueChanged = fun (minAge: Int, maxAge: Int) {
        //TODO use minAge and maxAge here
    }
```

Create `BindingAdapter` that will use lamba and feed parameters to the function above:

```
@BindingAdapter("onChangeListener")
fun RangeSlider.onChangeListener(function: (Int, Int) -> Unit) {
    addOnChangeListener { rangeSlider, value, fromUser ->
        val firstValue = this.values[0].toInt()
        val secondValue = this.values[1].toInt()
        function(firstValue, secondValue)
    }
}
```

Bind method from `BindingAdapter` in your layout with function in `ViewModel`:

```
<com.google.android.material.slider.RangeSlider
...
bind:onChangeListener="@{ viewModel.onValueChanged }"
/>
```